# Animated CSS underline on delay

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate (left to right) an underline with a transition delay on page load. I know how to get it working on hover, but not on load. Trying something like this but not sure why it won't work.

```
.under {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.under::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s; 
    transition-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two things to be noted while trying to achieve the effect that you are looking for:

- `text-decoration` property cannot be animated such that the underline goes from left to right.
- CSS `transition` is something that gets ***triggered only when there is a state change*** (either due to user interaction like hover, click etc or due to JavaScript like setTimeout). If you need the animation to happen on page load then you should use CSS `animation` with `@keyframes` rule.

As a side note, in your code the `transition-delay` is added before the `transition` property and the short-hand property has a delay value of `0s`. Since this is present later in the CSS, it will override the `transition-delay: 2s` that was specified earlier.

---

#### How to achieve this effect?

This is a rather simple effect that you are trying to achieve and so SVG is not really required. I would have recommended using SVG if the underline was curved (or) like an arc.

**Using a Pseudo-element:**

In the below snippet, I have used a pseudo-element and positioned it such that it produces a line that looks like an underline to the text. By animating pseudo-element's `width` from 0 - 100%, the required effect can be achieved. The `height` of the pseudo-element determines the border thickness and the `background-color` determines the color of the border.

```css
.underline {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.underline:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: red;
  animation: underline 2s ease-in-out 2s infinite; /* remove infinite if you want only once */
}
@keyframes underline {
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='underline'>Some underlined text</div>
<br>
<div class='underline'>Some lengthy underlined text</div>
```

---

**Using Linear Gradients:**

The same could also be achieved by using `linear-gradient` images as background to the element. Here the `background-size` in X-axis is animated from 0% - 100%. The `background-size` in Y-axis determines the border thickness and the `linear-gradient` determines the border color.

```css
.underline {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, red);
  background-size: 0% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left bottom;
  animation: underline 2s ease-in-out 2s infinite; /* remove infinite if you want only once */
}
@keyframes underline {
  to {
    background-size: 100% 2px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='underline'>Some underlined text</div>
<br>
<div class='underline'>Some lengthy underlined text</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the underline stay when the animation is finished?

Answer (score 0):

Edited the code to create a line that comes in left to right. This is an SVG line so it's not as easy to manipulate as regular div border or underline but the animation works. Give this a shot.

HTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg width="4cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 0 0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <title>Underline</title>
    <desc>Underline</desc>

    <line id="lineSVG" x1="0" y1="20" x2="100" y2="20" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>

<svg xml:space="preserve">
    <use class="under" xlink:href="#lineSVG" />
</svg>
```

CSS

```
.under {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    animation: DrawLine;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-duration: 2s; 
    stroke-dashArray: 1500;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
}

@keyframes DrawLine {
    to { stroke-dashOffset: 0; }
}
```

Comment: You could probably do that with stroke-dashOffset. I've done that before with SVG shapes; not sure if it can be done for borders or underlines. I'll see what I can figure out and let you know.