# Css button box-shadow transition

Tags: css, button

I'm having some trouble with making an transition effect on a button.

Using "box-shadow" I am able to create this:

```css
.load {
 color:black;
 border:none;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-left: 21px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #000000;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 transition-timing-function: ease-in;

}
.load:hover {
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 0 #000000;
}
```

```html
 <button class="load"> Home
   </button>
```

The shadow comes from the bottom and 3px into the button. I want it to be able to come from left to right, but still remaining at the 3px height.

I'm also pretty sure this website got it working, but i'm not able to extract the required CSS from inspecting it.

[Website](http://greyos.blogspot.com.au/p/privacy.html)

Thanks!

Comment: Does it mandatorily have to be with `box-shadow`? I don't think you can do it with shadows but there are other ways in which this is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641827/animated-css-underline-on-delay/35643574#35643574

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `:after` attribute. See my example below. The width of the after element changes between 0 and 100% to get the effect. You can tweak the settings of `.home-link:after` easily to your needs.

Using only `box-shadow` is not the best way and surely not the best practise for this effect.

```css
.home-link {
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: blue;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.home-link:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
}

.home-link:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="home-link">Home</button>
```